# Different optimization options for different files

Tags: rust-cargo

Binary produced by my rust program is to big under normal release profile. `opt-level = 'z'` results in to low performance.
I've identified file that is not performance critical and contributes significantly to binary size.
How do I set `opt-level = 'z'` for this file only?
What if this file is auto-generated in build.rs (It's rust code generated from slint)?

Answer (score 0):

I think one can separate the code that is to have different optimization options to a separate crate, depend on it in the main program and add:

```
[profile.release.package.crate-with-separated-out-code]
opt-level = "z"
```

I think this could be combined with use of workspace.

Unfortunately this does not work for me and is awkward to use.